# Is there a way I can configure Visual Studio, such that I can alt+tab through its windows?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

As my Visual Studio 2022 is currently configured, when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it only shows as a single window, this is regardless of how many windows there actually are.

For example, if I bring up the search results and then set them to "float", that subsequent floating can be dragged and place independently of the main window, but if I hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it only shows a single Visual Studio window.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> is a Windows keyboard shortcut to move through all open applications.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> in Visual Studio (it should be mapped to 'Windows.NextDocumentWindowNav') to bring up a window and tool navigator. Hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and use arrow keys (or mouse) to select window.

[image]

Comment: My answer is unintentionally almost the same with yours. I had failed to see your last sentence. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't tamper with the Windows default!

If your aim is to use the tool windows with keyboard shortcuts, **press and hold Ctrl+Tab**. This will bring the following pane and you can use the arrow keys to navigate between active code documents and tool windows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a older visual studio version, so I'm not sure if there are better ways for this. What I usually do is set a custom control for the dialogs that I use frequently, like output, results. Regardless if it's tied to the main window or floating, you can use the same control to open/close them.

Go to `Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard` Find the show commands that you need, set a shortcut key for that window.